# How to get cross-domain data using Javascript in django?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, api

Imagine, that you have two domains and you want them to interact through a Javascript mechanism.

So, what I've done so far is host two servers on different ports on my local machine. It seems that the request is being sent from one server to another, only it doesn't seem to return any data.

What do you think the problem is ? How can I solve it ?

P.S. Code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Also, kindly let me know if I should add any more details to the question

Comment: try [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about django, but the other domain must support CORS (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) and [the w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)).

Basically, the remote server must support the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Usually I just have my server set the header value to `*` to allow all origins to access data.

You might need to find more specific documentation for your particular webserver.  You might also want to watch the conversation between servers using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). It's a great little utility for finding out what's really happening with your HTTP requests/responses...

Comment: hey any idea, how I can get CORS to run on my django server, or even better If I could do both CORS and JSONP right ?

Comment: CORS is the way to do JSONP right. JSONP just creates a `<script>` tag and loads stuff since script tags don't need to follow the same origin policy. [This page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/) has information about setting HTTP headers in django. I really don't know much about it though, I use node.js and it's super simple there.

Comment: Also can't I solve this problem by somehow using hidden iframes ?

Comment: Ew. Just learn how to use CORS. It's really not that difficult. All you have to do is make sure you respond to `OPTIONS` and `GET` requests with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: what'll be the mimetype of the data I return from the server

Comment: Whatever you like. I prefer returning JSON (`application/json`), but you can return whatever you like. Using CORS is just like doing a regular AJAX call, except it's requesting from a different server than your server of origin.

Comment: Hey, now I've gotten the GET to work using CORS : ] but the POST's not working, any clue as to what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an extra header to host 2 to allow host 1. This site will help you http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: +1 for the link. I would just choose one that is already supported. I like node.js, and if there isn't much code already in django, it can easily be migrated to node.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is about to solve cross domain issues:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

jQuery has good functionality to support JSONP,

(just some googled link of this topic)

http://sangers.nu/blog/tech/20090129-jsonp-with-jquery

**EDIT:**

JSONP could look a little weird than at first sight :) basically should support JSONP notation (call callback method, if it is provided). So, it checks if 'callback' method is provided and instead of returning results like

```
{ some: 12 }
```

It does,

```
callback( { some: 12 } )
```

Here is my blog post on that:

http://www.beletsky.net/2010/07/json-jsonp-and-same-origin-policy-issue.html

Comment: Hey this looks really good, but I can't figure how passing how a callback variable makes it work ?

Comment: JSONP is just a hack for servers that don't support CORS. Now that CORS is available, JSONP should only be used as a fallback.

Comment: what'll be the mimetype of the data I return from the server

Comment: application/json, just exactly as json )

Answer (score 0):

jsonp is your option infact I used a django snippet available here

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2208/